# Cable identification: Euro plug to triangular shape

Tags: identification, cables

I recently found a cable near to a TV that didn't fit anywhere and didn't look familiar in any way. It's a Euro plug on the one end, and on the other end it's three contacts in a triangular shape, with an indicator(?) light on the back.

[picture of the cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzVQ2.jpg)

What might this cable be used for?

Potentially useful: country where I found this cable is South Africa

Dimensions: the unknown plug part is 32x20mm for the casing, the connector is 13x13mm, with the centers of the holes being 8mm apart from each other. Each hole is about 3mm in diameter

Comment: It looks like a non-standard (?) connector that performs the same function as the common IEC C5 or C13 [connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320). Time-honoured tradition is to throw it away, upon which the mating plug will appear within a matter of weeks.

Comment: We might call that a "cheater cord" that connects a normally earth grounded appliance to power without any polarity or earth ground.   Rarely needed or used these days as earth bonded jacks are used but extension cords may not have this so a cheater cord is sometimes unwisely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very unusual connector indeed, not even closely related to TVs.

It is used for a chargeable heating device, such as the one [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzdTT.jpg).

Comment: This isn't an answer so it should have been edited into your original question. If you've got a photo then add that in too rather than a link we all have to follow to see what you're talking about. Please delete this to save the moderator a job.

Comment: @transistor using the stackexchange app I was unable to add photos directly, presumably because of permissions